# how to loop through and get the last value

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Hi i have the following code:

```
m= list()
for i in range (1,6):
    set = base.Getentity(constants.ABAQUS,"SET",i)
    m.append(set)
    print(set)
```

and my result is

```
<Entity:0*17a:id:1>
<Entity:0*14g:id:2>
<Entity:0*14f:id:3>
<Entity:0*14a:id:4>
None
None
```

Here i have four elemnts in my set named set. Even though my code is written in ansa python, my question is very General

I would like to write a code which goes through the set and prints the last elemnt in my case

```
'<Entity:0*17a:id:4>'.
```

and aslo i dont want to use the range function so pls help me with writing the code.

Comment: Why are you calling the first element `<Entity:0*17a:id:1>` - the last?

Comment: `set` is a bad choice for a variable name because it clashes with `__builtins__.set`

Comment: hi, i have editd the question, i would like to get the last element

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at [Iterators](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html), that will help you loop through the list

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the range function, you can use xrange. It returns an xrange object, which is kind of like an iterator and generates the numbers on demand.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting None as the last two  values because there are no 'set' with the id 5 and 6 in your model
Use a filter before appending to the list m

```
m= list()
for i in range (1,6)
    set = base.Getentity(constants.ABAQUS,"SET",i)
    if set!=None:
        m.append(set)
```

Now you can just call m[-1] for the last entity

hope this helps